# How can I identify my netbook's chipset?

Tags: download, drivers

I've purchased a no-name netbook from malasia; and for the last year used Ubuntu on it just fine. I had a little trouble finding the Wireless driver, turns out the RT-3090 one worked.

But now I've come back to the dark side; whiped off Linux and installed WindowsXP. And belive it or not; no drivers. Dang. not even ethernet.

The netbook has no brand, make, or model. It's entirely no-name.

How can I find the chipset drivers?

Thanks!

Comment: Yes, USB thumb drives are working :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I prefer the lightweight CPU-Z

http://www.cpuid.com/softwares/cpu-z.html

Comment: As the only solution which is free and doesn't require me to download/install linux onto a specially formatted usb drive -- CPU-Z is the winner!

Answer (score 5):

Boot a live Linux distribution on the laptop somehow - either make a bootable USB stick, or burn a CD and boot fromm that.  I would recommend downloading an Ubuntu iso and using the "Try out" mode, or something like Knoppix.

Once you have linux running, open a root terminal and issue this command:

```
lspci
```

Assuming your distro is relatively recent, this should enumerate your chipset and pretty much every piece of hardware on your mainboard.  You might want to issue this command

```
update-pciids
```

to update lspci's database beforehand for the best information.

Answer (score 1):

[Everest](http://www.lavalys.com/) is probably the most comprehensive tool for this.

Comment: He'd have to install Windows and install the drivers in order to download and install that on the netbook, which is what he wants the software for to enable him to do in the first place.

Comment: I thought Windows XP was installed…

Comment: But he has no network drivers to download it.  I suppose he could transfer the software to the netbook using a USB flash drive though, if he has access to another computer.

Comment: @jason404: Assuming he has working USB.  Which is usually the case, but I've dealt with hardware where Windows wasn't able to enumerate all the buses without vendor drivers, and so some of the multiple USB controllers were unreachable.

Comment: @ephemient: Yeah, he's best off putting Linux back on it and using some tools from there.

Answer (score 1):

[Speccy's](http://www.piriform.com/speccy) a pretty good lightweight one too

Comment: He'd have to install Windows and install the drivers in order to download and install that on the netbook, which is what he wants the software for to enable him to do in the first place.